# Class SSKeychain is implemented in both framwork and appilcation iOS

Tags: swift, cocoapods, sskeychain

My podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'

target 'xxx' do
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'RSKImageCropper'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
  pod 'Base64', '~> 1.1.2'
  pod 'BGTableViewRowActionWithImage'
  pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'TYMProgressBarView'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'NestSDK'
end
```

[image]

I have this error message in console :

objc[3645]: Class SSKeychain is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices (0x1b27d32b0) and /var/containers/Bundle/Application/9A955CA3-9741-4867-9307-0870BBD6CF08/xxx.app/xxx (0x10112eab8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: Probably a problem in your project settings, not in your pods. Maybe you are including an `*.m` file into your header?

Comment: i dont have SSKeychain.m in my header, i have SSKeychain in my pod but i didnt install it. i added picture

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 10 there is a private class called SSKeychain. That's why you are getting this error. Because of this the `SSKeychain` [has been renamed](https://github.com/soffes/SAMKeychain/issues/154#issuecomment-248234063) to `SAMKeychain`.

Since you haven't implicitly added `SSKeychain` in your `Podfile`, I suppose it's a dependency of one of other Pods you use. You can find this out by looking into `Podfile.lock`. Once you found the library which has this dependency check if its podspec has been already updated to use `SAMKeychain` instead.